# Contenteditable div on ionic application not cascading

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I'm having problems on creating a div element with content editable in Ionic application, the text of that div works fine, but when you edit every break line you make is created another div inside the original one, like this: `<div contenteditable="true"> This can be edited <div> but this not</div></div>` and this can't be even clickable.

I did the same test without the ionic bundle and works fine.

I create this codepen [http://codepen.io/lhrossi/pen/XNBbpm ] reproducing the issue, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's an issue only in Chrome, but I didn't test it.

The solution is to add `display:inline-block` on the element. This way it will add `<br>` instead of `<div></div>` for a new line.

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
```